# This logic seems correct but its not working . Is there any mistake?

Tags: c++

The program is to reverse the contents of an array .
For example if the array contained {1,2,3,4,5}
it should display {5,4,3,2,1}

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    tmp=a[i];
    a[i]=a[n-1-i];
    a[n-1-i]=tmp;
}
```

Comment: If you look closely, this loop reverses twice resulting in the original array.

Comment: after this if i use another for loop and print the array... I am getting {1,2,3,4,5}

Comment: can you please explain further?

Comment: @Targeryen take a piece of paper and a pencil and you should be able to figure out yourself what's wrong with your approach

Comment: How can i fix this?

Comment: @Targeryen, the idea is in swapping first element with the last one, second with the second from the end and so on, i.e in your example: 1-5, 2-4. There is '3' in the middle that should not be swapped.

Comment: @suvenpandey You don't have to post your own answer as a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reverse an array you dont iterate over entire array. That would lead to reversing array twice.
Try `for(i=0;i<n/2;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < n--; i++)
{
    tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[n];
    a[n] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are reversing the array in-place, hence after the first step you have the first and the last element in its correct position. After iterating over half the elements you have the first half and the second half in its corret position. Now, iterating over all elements, you swap each element twice which results in the original array.

Comment: seems like someone is on a voting spree, if you know what is wrong would be cool to let me know

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 0, j = n - 1;
for (i = 0; i < n/ 2; i++, j--)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good questions should also explain why this code helps and how it solves the problem.